# AuthMode gets confused w/ multiple logged in users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-script-addon

I'm bumping into a weird problem in Google Apps Script, working on a Slides add-on.

When I run the add-on in an incognito window with just one user logged in (call it User B), everything works fine.

When I run the add-on with multiple users logged in (call it Users A and B in the same Chrome tab), it seems like Apps Script gets confused around the authorization. When I try to use the add-on as User B (as evidenced by the profile showing up in the upper right corner), all functionality of the add-on fails, I'm guessing because it lacks authorization. Note that the add-on has remain installed on User B's account this whole time, and it still works in the incognito window with just User B logged in.

Any tips on this? Is there a way to "force" the add-on to use the authorization of User B in the multi-logged-in case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Having multiple log-ins active in the same browser is known to cause issues with Google Authorization](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374).

The default account (typically the account that was first logged into) takes precedence over any other accounts. Google has yet to fully resolve this. Current work-around is to recommend to your users to log out of all other accounts.

Comment: Thanks for linking that! Wow, that's really unfortunate.

I ended up implementing a workaround where I created a new menu item that goes directly to the new modal I wanted to pop up. Then in the original place where I tried to invoke that modal, I added a try/catch where, if there's an error, a new message shows up in the sidebar asking the user to try the new menu option. Not a great experience, but at least it's somewhat of an escape hatch...

Comment: How do I determine if the user has logged in from multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got it solved by changing the link as follows:

[https://script.google.com/a/{any_character}/macros/s/{deployment_id}/exec](https://script.google.com/a/%7Bany_character%7D/macros/s/%7Bdeployment_id%7D/exec)

Note that my app was set public so anyone can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this url to test instead:

```
https://script.google.com/a/{domain name}/macros/s/{token}/exec
```