# Why is my script pushing an incorrect URL? [/u/2 inserted into script URL]

Tags: debugging, url, google-apps-script, google-account

I'm an GAS novice, attempting to keep an application afloat during a time of transition, and the following issue began presenting recently. Although the script is pushing a URL (for another published script) into a menu item link ... (see images)

[image: set variable as URL]

[image: include in nav item hyperlink]

...the URL set via the script is not what is being accessed by some (not all) individuals in the published application. Rather than their link opening a URL beginning with `"https://script.google.com/macros/s/AK..."`, some users being directed to URLs that begin with `"https://script.google.com/macros/u/2/s/AK..."`.  (Note the addition of the **`/u/2`**) Please see screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of URL linked through published application]

**Any thoughts on how to identify potential issues is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/u/2` (the number could vary) are added by Google on web applications that use Google accounts when the user is signed in a Google account.

The numbers vary when the user have signed in in multiple Google accounts:

- 0 is for the default account
- 1 for the second account
- 2 for the third account, etc.

Regarding potencial issues, there is know issue related to this that usually happens when the client-side code calls a server side function that requires to access a private doc, file, form, slide, spreadsheet.

Related

- [AuthMode gets confused w/ multiple logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54751857/15954511595451)

Comment: Thank you Rubén! I will advise users to access via incognito mode rather than signing into a separate account.

Comment: @K.RhodieEdwards If you have few users that might work but if it don't you could add a try.. catch and show a message to ask them that and/or share the spreadsheet with all their accounts.