# Trouble publishing WebApp through GS

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm using Google Script to develop a web app where information is added and sent to a spreadsheet but I'm having problems simply getting the web app to publish a finable page.

Following a tutorial I found, I have the script

```
function doGet(){

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("cash");

}
```

I then created a new html file with the same name (cash) and Tried to create just a header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>

        <h1>Runner Cash</h1>

      </body>
    </html>
```

From here, I've saved everything then gone through the publish - deploy as web app - create - then I go to click in dev by clicked "test web app for your latest code" but immediately get hit with an error
[image]

Anyone have thoughts on why it's not publishing the page?

***edit*** I've opened my project in an incognito mode and I was able to open in development, /dev, but I still can't open the actual url. When I do I get an error "Script function not found: doGet".

How come I can only access /dev in incognito and why is the function supposedly not working?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Try using Google Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled. First open your project then open the /dev link.

Comment: So this worked but now I have more questions.
Will I only be able to work on this via incognito? I'm able to see the /dev link but I can't open the link itself. The error is "Script function not found: doGet ". Is this now a new issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to  include what you tried as well a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you have signed-in in multiple Google accounts and that you created your script using one of your secondary accounts. If this is correct, then you are facing a known "issue".

Workarounds

1. As you already did, try using another web browser or your web browser in private mode. Be sure to sign-in only in the account used to create your script.
2. Sign-out of all your accounts, then sign-in again first with the account used to create your script.

Regarding the error

> Script function not found: doGet

double check that your script hasn't a typo and that you saved the file having the `doGet` function.

Related

- [Script function not found: doGet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22272308/1595451)
- ["function not found" error when making both GET and POST requests to a Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22617138/1595451)
- [AuthMode gets confused w/ multiple logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54751857/1595451)
- [Why is my script pushing an incorrect URL? [/u/2 inserted into script URL]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63709693/1595451)

Comment: If it is the case that it has to do with multiple accounts: a tip: Create a chrome 'account' for each gmail. This will solve that problem https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9025411?hl=en