# Some users get an error and weird URL when trying to access my Google Script. Debug Tips Welcome

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-account

I wrote two small Google Scripts that present simple forms to fill in. Most of my user community has no trouble using them. A small minority of users can never open the forms, instead they get "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time" error page for both forms. I can't find any common thread for why only some users fail. I've tested on multiple browsers on multiple machines, even on android devices, it never fails for me.

A couple of things I've noted:

- when it fails for them the URL is re-written. The proper url starts with https://script.google.com/macros/s/... but for broken users when they paste that in they instead get https://script.google.com/macros/u/3/s/... (notice the "u/3" at the end)
- There is no execution log created when they try to access the site, so I have no way to debug what's going on.
- The app is permissioned so "Anyone" can access it, and it runs as my account

Sorry, I realize this problem description is impossibly vague. Any debug suggestions would be extremely welcome. I'm not a regular Google App Script developer, so I'm kinda stumbling in the dark with this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/u/3` means that the user have signed-in into multiple Google accounts, the number correspond to the zero-based index of the account in the order that the user followed to sign-in, 0 is for the default account, 1 is to de second account, 2 is for the thirds account and so on.

So, on your test include this use case, a user signed-in into multiple Google accounts.

NOTE: It's known that the HTML Service do not handle as expected this use case.

Related

- [AuthMode gets confused w/ multiple logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54751857/1595451)
- [We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60230776/1595451)
- [Why is my script pushing an incorrect URL? [/u/2 inserted into script URL]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63709693/1595451) (possible duplicate)

Comment: You're a Super Hero! I can't thank you enough, that's exactly the problem. I've been searching for this thing on and off for months now, it was SO frustrating. Thank you!